# Extended Controller (Controller decorator) NestJS

Tags: controller, decorator, nestjs, typescript-decorator

I am trying to extend a controller with functionality to grab any request going to it and call some function right away. So I created this decorator and placed it on top of my class definition. Though I encountered a couple of problems I need your help with solving.

1. For some reason I can't reuse this ExtendedController on multiple classes, it only processes the endpoints related to the last attached class, all previously attached classes react with 404.
2. I don't know how to attach to SomeClass all prev decorators that might have been attached to the class or the endpoint.

Any thoughts on solving these would be helpful!

```
import {
 ControllerOptions,
 Controller,
 Req,
 Res,
 Next,
 All,
} from '@nestjs/common';

import { Request, Response } from 'express';

export const ExtendedController = (
 prefixOrOptions?: string | ControllerOptions,
): ClassDecorator => {
 return <TFunction extends Function>(target: TFunction) => {

   const someClass: any = base => {
     @Controller(prefixOrOptions as any)
     class SomeClass extends base {

       @All()
       rpc(
         @Req() req: Request,
         @Res() res: Response,
         @Next() next,
       ): any {
         console.log('Call some function here');
         return next();
       }
     }

     return SomeClass;
   };

   return someClass(target as any);
 };
};
```

And use it as

```
@ExtendedController('user')
export class UserController {
  @Post()
  hello() {
    console.log('HELLO');
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not use something like an interceptor?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel could you show an example?

Comment: I mean, what's the function supposed to do? [Nest's docs on interceptors](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors) show how to set them up and a basic logging example